# What does page-focused approach mean?

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

Microsoft writes "Razor Pages makes coding page-focused scenarios easier and more productive." 
But what does the this mean? I have tried looking up page-focused keyword but found nothing useful.

Comment: Application that behaves like a website, for example forms with database access.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well generally it tries to say that it gives you better control of frontend scenarios. If you want to create for example html code for a list of products you could it with a foreach loop using Razor.

Page-focused scenarios are scenarios (problems) that are mostly about the presentation (razor, html etc). There is no clear interpenetration.

You could think that a page-focused scenario is for example receiving a list and then displaying it. The display part is the page focused. Or for example depending on the user who is logged in to change the buttons. If a user is logged in you want to show the button for logout and if he's logged out you want to show the button for logged in. The above are examples of page-focused scenarios